# PHPMailer from .local email address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send notification emails from a website. When I was testing it, I set it up using Gmail SMTP and it was working normally. Now on Production, I need to set it up to send emails from the customer's LOCAL email address (username@domain.local). The customer has his own email server.

Is SMTP still used in this situation? I tried to research it quite a bit but I really couldn't find any reference to this.

```
$mail->IsSMTP();                      
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;            
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";          
$mail->Host       = "domain.local";    // or an IP that was also provided by the customer labeling it as "host" for the email server
$mail->Port       = 25;              
$mail->Username   = "username@domain.local";  
$mail->Password   = "password";         

$mail->SetFrom('username@domain.local', 'Webname');
$mail->[...]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The one provided by the customer which is either "domain.local" where domain is the name the customer gave it or an IP address that he also provided and said is the "host" for that server.

Comment: why local? The local email is usually just for what it sounds like, local to the server email.  Have the client set you up a correct account and tell you the port/auth scheme.

Comment: That was my take on it too but I'd already checked with him and he confirmed that he uses it for outgoing non-local emails as well. If I do want to use this setup, is SMTP used?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to test in any email client, assuming its IP is allowed.

Comment: Okay thanks. Also using the above code as a base, I try the Host as IP, it gives: "Failed to connect to server: (0)". I try "domain.local", it gives: "Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)"

Is this expected?

Comment: If the host isn't an SMTP server, can I still use the above code snippet?